# Strip of substring from a string in swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have a string with brackets in it from which have to remove/strip the substring. 
 For ex:

"8383838383(1234)" //string value

"8383838383" // desired result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? In what way is it not working? Please give more examples - you current result can be achieved by simply stripping the last 6 characters off.

Comment: or just using the first 10 characters!.

Comment: was using name.removeAtIndex()  method and the index was found by string.indexOf .. but not working @luk2302

Comment: when from "(" occurence @Russell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"8383838383(1234)".substringToIndex(string.rangeOfString("(")!.startIndex)
// "8383838383"
```

Comment: that was so cool , I was trying with indexOf and removeAtIndex. thanks Tim

Comment: Done :) and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Tim's suggestion -

```
let strFull = "8383838383(1234)"

var str = strFull.substringToIndex(strFull.rangeOfString("(")!.startIndex)
```

Comment: In what way is your answer different? Isn't it exactly the same? Introducing a variable does not change anything.

Comment: In @Tim's example, there are two calls to the source string - `subStringToIndex` uses the string literal, but the second call to `rangeOfString` uses `string` which isn't defined.  By adding the variable, we can reference it both times.